# Print result into input box rather than into URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, datatables

I would like to print the result value into an input box that looks like this for example:

`<input type="text" id="mylink"/>`

Rather than automatically updating the URL, is it possible to replicate current functionality into a text box rather than update in the URL so that the end result is copyable URL links?

An example of the current script in action is available at http://www.catchingtherain.com/wpdatatables-merged-column-test/

Currently, any filters applied are automatically put into the URL. I have tried what I can but seem to run into errors trying to get this thing to work but again I'm not the best at Javascript after all.

```
jQuery(window).load(function(){
  wpDataTables.table_1.addOnDrawCallback(function(){
    var params={};
    jQuery('.wpDataTableFilterSection').each(function(i, obj) {
      if ( inputbox = obj.id.match("table_1_(.+)_filter_sections") ) {
        if (jQuery(obj).find('input').val()) {
          var key='wdt_column_filter['+inputbox[1]+']';
          params[key] = jQuery(obj).find('input').val();
        }
      }
    }); 
    history.pushState('','','?'+jQuery.param(params));
  });
});
```

Comment: It badly looks like you're using some copied code without having any clue of how it works. Don't do that, your page can easily get XSSed.

Comment: Ah, thank you for the advice. I'll see what I can do :)

Comment: That was rather a generic advice, the provided code seems to be safe ...

Comment: Ah ok, got you! Cheers mate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
    history.pushState('','','?'+jQuery.param(params));
```

with

```
jQuery("#mylink").val(jQuery.param(params))
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply champ! Appreciated.

Comment: Tried it out, seems to be pushing an error still, since I don't have the best of knowledge with JS I'll have to hire someone to get it working, should be a better route overall. Ty for your inputs, greatly appreciated.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: "#mylink".val is not a function

Comment: Sounds like you forgot to call `jQuery()` or `$()` around `"#mylink"`

Comment: Spot on legend! Last question if you don't mind, is there a way to add the current URL at the start? I mean I'm sure it's possible but my expertise in this field is quite lacking ;) I've tried a few methods including for example jQuery("#mylink").html("example.com/")+$.val(jQuery.param(params)); but this isn't the right way to actually insert it with the .val. Basically want the result to be  example.com/ followed by the variable.

Comment: The concatenation has to be inside the `.val()` argument: `.val("example.com/" + jQuery.param(params))`